# There is no height set for the scroll bar, why is it displayed

Tags: html, css

#### weird scroll bar,if set overflow-x:hidden and line-height lt 20px,it will show;

#### and I didn't set any height;

#### the test url is below;

[demo address](https://codepen.io/mysecret/pen/ZEQwgBm)

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    html,body {height: 100%;line-height: 1;overflow:hidden;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section style="overflow-x: hidden;">
    <div data-v-ac8adc6c="">member manage</div>
    <div data-v-ac8adc6c="">member manage</div>
    <div data-v-ac8adc6c="">member manage</div>
    <div data-v-ac8adc6c="">member manage</div>
    <div data-v-ac8adc6c="">member manage</div>
    <div data-v-ac8adc6c="">member manage</div>
    <div data-v-ac8adc6c="">member manage</div>
    <div data-v-ac8adc6c="">member manage</div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set margin of the body to zero:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

and set height of the section element to the height of the body:

```
<section style="overflow-x: hidden; height: 100%;">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but what I want to know is why is there a scrollbar that doesn't have a height

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean

Comment: height of the section element (and also many other elements) is set by default to the sum of heights of elements inside it

Comment: thanks bro,but why if I remove the style "overflow-x:hidden;" or set the style "line-height:20px",the scroll bar will disappear?Don't you think it's strange,I never set height property for section,as far as I know,Setting the height is necessary for the scroll bar to appear.